# Was Joseph 10 or 17 when sold into slavery by his brothers?

Tags: joseph, bible, age

I know Genesis 37:2 says he was 17, but the Hebrew word here for "seventeen" is the word "*asar* or *esreh*" (according to Strong's #6240), which is translated to "ten". I'm wandering where the discrepancy lies, and what to take from this. Is this word more of a generic word? If the word does literally mean *ten*, then why would it be translated to 17? Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I didn't look hard enough. For eser; ten (only in combination), i.e. -teen; also (ordinal) -teenth -- (eigh-, fif-, four-, nine-, seven-, six-, thir-)teen(-th), + eleven(-th), + sixscore thousand, + twelve(-th).

Comment: https://biblehub.com/interlinear/genesis/37.htm

Answer (score 1):

The Hebrew in Gen 37:2 consists of two words: שְׁבַֽע־עֶשְׂרֵ֤ה = seven - ten = seventeen

There is nothing mysterious and nothing unusual about this.